# Converting date string to number for comparison

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I have dates in this format:

Jan. 4, 2011

I need to convert these dates to numbers then compare to make sure sort is correct (ascending or descending).

I've tried using Date.parse(s), but I keep getting NaN back as value.  I believe it's the period after the 3 letter abbreviation thats screwing it up.

How do I convert these date string to number?

Comment: remove the `.` via string operations? `Jan 4 2011` parses just fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDate = "Jan. 4, 2011";
myDate = myDate.replace('.','');
var dateType = Date.parse(myDate);
```

dateType should give you a number

Comment: I edited your post because you have to reassign the value of myDate back to myDate when you use .replace(), and you shouldn't replace "." with ","...you need to replace it with "". I don't think it's necessary, but you can replace "," with "" as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's a more streamlined way of doing it than I came up with.  (took the first 3 characters of string, and rest of string after period), concatenated it, then parsed it. will save a few lines in the test. :), especially since the dates throughout the site are in a variety of formats.